# printf not working (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

So I have been learning how to work with pointers and this simple program won't run and I can't figure out what is wrong
I think the problem is this line of code:

```
printf("Address of pointer variable = %x \n",pointer_p);
```

I also tried with `printf("Address of pointer variable = %x \n",&pointer_p);` still no results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {    
    int val = 30;
    int *pointer_p;
    pointer_p = &val;
    //shows the address of val (hexadecimal)
    printf("Address of val = %x\n", &val);
    printf("Address of pointer variable = %x\n", pointer_p);
    //shows the value of this address
    printf("Value of pointer = %d\n", *pointer_p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"won't run"_ ? Did you compile it? (It runs perfectly fine for me.)

Comment: So what happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I've just tested this and it works fine.  What exactly is not working as you would expect?

Comment: I can assure you, from long personal experience, that `printf` is working.

Answer (score 3):

To print addresses of any kind, you have to use `%p` and cast the pointer to `void*`:

```
printf("Address where pointer is pointing = %p\n", (void*) pointer_p);
printf("Address of pointer variable = %p\n", (void*) &pointer_p);
```

See [printf documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Please bear in mind, that `pointer_p` returns the address it's pointing to. If
you want the address of the variable, you have to use `&pointer_p`. See the
`printf`s above.

Comment: @dyz Disagree with "There is no need to explicitly cast to `void*`". C spec says about `"%p"`: " The argument shall be a pointer to `void`".  `int *` needs not have the same presentation as `void *`  "Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements."  Casting to `void*` makes for the most portable code.

Comment: @chux Isn't there an implicit cast to `void*` here?

Comment: @dyz Per §6.5.2.2 6 (semantics about ... argument)  implies no such implicit cast,

Comment: @chux Agree. For some reason I was thinking about a function with `void*` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To print out the address of pointer_p (not the address of val which is the value of pointer_p):

```
printf("Address of pointer variable = %p \n", (void *)&pointer_p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format specifier.

use `%p` instead of `%x` like this :

```
printf("Adress pointed to  = %p \n", pointer_p);
printf("Adress of pointer = %p \n", &pointer_p);
```

here is a [link](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm) that may be useful.